# How create worked template DropDown into ListView?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown, kendo-listview

Here my [snipet](http://dojo.telerik.com/@nim/AsEtU/6). I have two problems. First, i can't view selected item, after i select item in dropdown and save. Second, if create new item without select domain, it has wrong site code. Domain can't be zero because site_data not contains item with code 0;

Help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't see the selected item because you did not set `selectable` to `true` in the ListView.
2. You get value `0` for domain because you did not define a default value for `site` in your `dataSource` so being a number the default value is `0` and it is not important the fact that there is no `0` in the list of values that you provide (there is no such validation). So you should have it as:

   ```
   document.provider_source = new kendo.data.DataSource({
     pageSize: 6,
     schema: {
       model: {
         id: "code",
         fields: {
           code: { editable: false, nullable: true },
           site: { type: "number", defaultValue: 1 },
           login: { type: "string" },
           pass: { type: "string" }
         }
       }
     },
     data: provider_data
   });
   ```

Where I set `defaultValue` for `site` to `1` (first value in the list).

Your code modified here: http://dojo.telerik.com/@OnaBai/Ihab

Comment: You do not understand me correctly the first question. I meant that the view should be the "Domain: apple.com", but not so: "Domain: 1"

The second question is really solved thanks.

Comment: Regarding the first question, if you store the value (code) it will show the value unless you use some code to get the domain that corresponds to the code. Is that what you want?

Comment: I want see domain name, now i see code. I can't make worked view template

Comment: <script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template2">
            <dt>Domain</dt>
            <dd>#:site#</dd> What i need write here?